# PHP: INSERT DATA BY SELECTION TAG HTML WITH PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code to insert the data selection from select tag in html but i doesn't work perfectly when i put a value number in text input i would like someone helps me with that. otherwise, when i click in add_btn without value the insertion of data is added in MySQL databases.

HTML->

```
  <form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="post">
                    <select name="type" class="add__type" >
                        <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
                        <option value="exp">-</option>
                    </select>                
                 <select  name="description" class="add__description" title="h" >
                   <option  value="Food">Food</option>
                   <option  value="Salary">Salary</option>
                   <option  value="Home">Home</option>
                   <option  value="Car">Car</option>
                   <option  value="Education">Education</option>
                   <option  value="Gift">Gift</option>
                   <option  value="Travle"> Travle </option>
                   <option  value="Fun">Fun</option>
                        </select>
                <input name="value" type="number" class="add__value">
           <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
            </form>
     <script src="script/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

PHP-> userinfo.php

```
  <?php
        include_once('db.php');

        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $value = $_POST['value'];

        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO budget VALUES('$type', '$description' , '$value')"))
          echo "Successfully Inserted";
        else
          echo "Insertion Failed";
?>
```

PHP -> db.php

```
<?php
      $conn = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '');
      $db   = mysql_select_db ('test');
?>
```

Comment: Your code is severely vulnerable towards database injections. Not only are you using a deprecated api (`mysql` rather than `mysqli` or `PDO`) but you're injecting variables directly into your string, which is a big nogo (as users can generate any SQL query that want to eg `'); --` to break your code.

Comment: I will checkout. Thank you.

Comment: @Tony can you show us the output of the following code after submitting the form.
**echo "INSERT INTO budget VALUES('$type', '$description' , '$value')");**

Comment: @FaiyazAlam this is the output of the code : INSERT INTO budget VALUES('inc', '' , '')

Comment: @FaiyazAlam and this is the other output without putting value INSERT INTO budget VALUES('inc', 'Food' , '')

Comment: @Tony in both output you are not getting the value field.
Try print_r($_POST) and check if the value is in this variable.

Comment: @FaiyazAlam you're right I didn't get the value : "Array ( [type] => inc [description] => Food [value] => ) Error: 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: @Tony try this:

 $value = $_POST['thisistestvalue'];
 <input name="thisistestvalue" type="number" class="add__value">

Comment: @FaiyazAlam "Notice: Undefined index: thisistestvalue in C:\xampp\htdocs\userInfo.php on line 6
Array ( [type] => inc [description] => Food [value] => ) Error: 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: mind changing the CAPS to lowercase for the title? it's considered as yelling

Comment: @FaiyazAlam Finally, I found the the answer; I forgot to use the type button tag "submit" :)

Answer (score 1):

If in your database table have Auto Increment value like id you need to declare inside the values field like this

`INSERT INTO budget VALUES('','$type', '$description' , '$value')`

If you want to what type of error for inserting in the query you need to check the what is the error. in yours, if condition be like

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO budget VALUES('','$type', '$description' , '$value')"))
   echo "Successfully Inserted";
else
   echo "Error: <br>" . mysql_error($conn);
```

And you need to change your default values like `value`, `type` this is no issue here but my advice is to avoid default words for define variable.

**Final:**

Avoid using MySQL because Mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead

Comment: thank you for your help, but i get this alert after submitting : "Error: 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Comment: I have just three columns : Type, Description and Value.

Comment: @Tony did you find the answer?

Comment: No, I didn't find it  :(

Answer (score -1):

You're using an outdated method to do this. Have a look here : http://php.net/manual/it/book.mysqli.php

I suggest you also to check datas before insert them into your database. you are not checking anything to protect you to SqlInjection (you can start with a simple `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Correct the line 5 from this

`$value = $_POST['value'];`

to this

`$value = $_POST['description'];`

The fact that the data may not get inserted successfully can be due to an issue with your database. Be sure that your columns have the property to accept `varchar` instead of the `text` because if you try to insert number to a filed that only want letters your query will not work.

Comment: That's not the problem here. He's getting an undefined index in the $_POST.

Comment: @omerowitz undefined index can be removed by using isset(). But user has not mentioned this issue in his description.